# minimum number of neighbors for scRNA-seq analysis

Tags: scrnaseq

Many scRNA-seq clustering/visualization methods are based on nearest neighbors. The maximum number of neighbors is limited by the neighborhood size. Is there a method to determine the minimum number of neighbors? Now that most datasets are well in the thousands of cells, this point is largely irrelevant, so maybe that is why not much guidance on this issue is available. However, if you something like 50 cells, it becomes far more critical.

If you have a deeply sequenced dataset, your neighbors should be more reliable (less noisy) than one with shallow coverage, so you should be able to use less. Is there a way to somehow quantify that?

Comment: Honestly I feel like you could do a PhD around this question.